# please let me know how to load the List<dataset> of first dataset values to List<Person>

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I am trying to load the values from a `List<dataset>` to `List<Person>`

I've written the following code, but am unsure what to do next

```
public List<Person> AddressFinderBLL_GetAddressbyName(String pfname,)
{ 
    List<Person> Per= new List<Person>();
    List<DataSet> lstPer = new List<DataSet>(); 
    lstPer = Adal.AddressFinderDAL_GenerateDatabyName(
      pfname, pfnameval, plname, plnameval);
      //here List<Dataset> lstPer loaded with values from back end foreach(DataRow item in lstPer[0].Tables[0].Rows)
{
    // here i need to assign the values to List<Person> from List<Dataset>[0].tables[0].rows; 
}
```

Person class has following attributes                                                           class class Person
    {

```
    public String _firstname,_middlename;

    public Person()
    {
    }
    public String Firstname
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstname;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstname = value;
        }

    }

    public String Middlename
    {
        get 
        {
            return _middlename;
        }
        set
        {
            _middlename = value;
        }
    }
```

} please let me know

Comment: yes, i want to know how to proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what column names your DataSet has, but here's an approximation:

```
List<Person> pers = lstPer[0].Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
                    Select(r=> new Person() { 
                        FirstName = r.Field<string>("fieldname1"),
                        MiddleName = r.Field<string>("fieldname2")
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Incidentally, a method returning a list of DataSets seems kind of unlikely.  Are you sure that part's right?  Perhaps it returns one DataSet that contains multiple tables?

Comment: @salvaanand: This is correct if you want the persons of the first table in the first dataset. [My approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12587475/284240) is correct if you want the persons of the first table in all datasets.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  His commented out code said "need to assign the values to List<Person> from List<Dataset>[0].tables[0].Rows" so I assumed it was just the first one.  But yours is probably a safer assumption.

Comment: @AnnL.: Yes, i've seen it later. But since you've added already your answer, i havent edited mine. So OP has the choice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (i don't know the columns of your table):

```
Per = (from ds in lstPer
      from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
      select new Person(){
          FirstName = row.Field<String>("FirstName"),
          MiddleName = row.Field<String>("MiddleName")
      }).ToList();
```

Note that you need to add `using system.Linq` since above is a linq-query(Linq-To-DataSet).

Comment: Thanks to all of you  @Paul D'Ambra,Tim schmelter,Ann L, for your support but i am unable to use method AsEnumerable() eventhough i had included  namespace system.Data.DataSetExtensions ,however it is working fine with paul D'Ambra code

Comment: Thanks to all, @Tim schemelter, Ann L, it is working fine now because i had corrected my mistake by using lstper[0].Tables[0].AsEnumerable but earlier i was checking for lstper[0].Tables[0].Rows.AsEnumerable() ...(..) i would like to inform you all 3 peoples code's were helpful

Answer (score 0):

All from memory so YMMV but I'd expect it to be

```
public List<Person> AddressFinderBLL_GetAddressbyName(String pfname,)
{
   List<Person> Per= new List<Person>();
   List<DataSet> lstPer = new List<DataSet>();
   lstPer = Adal.AddressFinderDAL_GenerateDatabyName(pfname, pfnameval, plname, plnameval);
   //here List<Dataset> lstPer loaded with values from back end 
foreach(DataRow item in lstPer[0].Tables[0].Rows)
       {
              // here i need to assign the values to List<Person> from List<Dataset>[0].tables[0].rows; 
          var p = new Person();
//it isn't clear what structure item will have. let's assume that it has 2 columns. one is         //firstname and the other is last name 
          p.FirstName = item[0];
          p.Middlename = item[1];
          Per.Add(p);
       }
```

But as per the other answers you'll get so much more out of a little reading around LINQ!